# delete the value of variabel in batch after code is done

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanna make an if/else statement where if my variabel is empty it has to echo an text but it is never empty because it keeps giving me the previous value I wrote in cmd. How can I possibly solve this, I tried using startlocal and endlocal but I couldn't get it to work this is my code:

```
@echo off
set /p "Input= text:"
FOR %%a IN (%Input%) DO (
    IF "%%a"=="" (echo Write atleast 1 word) else (
        ECHO %%a
    )
)
```

In this picture u can see that if I write something first and click enter it puts everything underneath each other but the second time I wrote nothing and got the same values back
[Cmd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYyqF.png)

Comment: `startlocal` didn't work because the command is `setlocal`

Comment: When `%input%` is empty, `for` has nothing to process and so doesn't `echo` anything. Check *before* you enter the loop: `if "%input%" == "" echo no input & goto :eof`. A `setlocal` between `@echo off` and `set /p` destroys any variables when the script ends. (to be precise, an implicit `endlocal` is executed for each open `setlocal`, when the script ends). Nevertheless, clearing the variable before `set /p` (like @lit suggested) is good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove whatever is in the `input` variable at the beginning.

```
@echo off
SET "Input="
set /p "Input= text:"
```